# Difference in calculating eigenvectors wih Java and Python

Tags: java, python, numpy, eigenvector, apache-commons-math

As a current task, I need to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a 120*120 matrix. For start, I tested those calculations on a simple 2 by 2 matrix in both Java (Apache Commons Math library) and Python 2.7 (Numpy library). I have a problem with eigenvector values not matching, as show below :

```
//Java
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.EigenDecomposition;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.MatrixUtils;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;

public class TemporaryTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[][] testArray = {{2, -1}, {1, 1}};
    RealMatrix testMatrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(testArray);
    EigenDecomposition decomposition = new EigenDecomposition (testMatrix);
    System.out.println("eigenvector[0] = " + decomposition.getEigenvector(0));
    System.out.println("eigenvector[1] = " + decomposition.getEigenvector(1));
}
```

Output of eigenvectors are shown as {real_value + imaginary_value; real_value + imaginary_value}:

```
//Java output
eigenvector[0] = {-0.8660254038; 0}
eigenvector[1] = {0.5; 1}
```

Same code in Python, but using Numpy library:

```
# Python
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

w, v = LA.eig(np.array([[2, -1], [1, 1]]))
print (v[:, 0])
print (v[:, 1])
```

Output of eigenvectors in Python are shown similarly, [real+imag        real+imag]:

```
[ 0.35355339+0.61237244j  0.70710678+0.j        ]
[ 0.35355339-0.61237244j  0.70710678-0.j        ]
```

My concern is, why are those vectors different ? Is there something that I am missing ? Ty for any kind of help or advice

Comment: Those vectors in the Java output are not eigenvectors.  `getEigenvector(i)` returns a `RealVector`, but your matrix has complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  I don't know how the Apache Commons Math Library represents a complex eigenvector; hopefully someone familiar with the library will help you translate the real values returned by the Java functions into the actual complex eigenvectors.

Comment: I agree, but as you can see, even the real values do not match :-/

Comment: The java ones aren't even normalised..

Comment: By any chance is your 120*120 matrix symmetric?  If so, you won't have to deal with the problem of the `EigenDecomposition` methods returning only real values.

Comment: Is there a way to check symmetry in Python ?

Comment: You could use something like `np.allclose(A, A.T)`.  But you may know from the problem itself if the matrix should be symmetric.  For example, a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is symmetric by construction; there would be no need to check it in your code (except maybe to check for bugs in the code that generates the matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache Commons Math 3, `EigenDecomposition` accepts nonsymmetric matrices, but it returns results using the classes `RealVector` and `RealMatrix`.  To get the actual complex results, you have to combine the appropriate real results into complex conjugate pairs.

In the case of the eigenvectors, you got:

```
eigenvector[0] = {-0.8660254038; 0}
eigenvector[1] = {0.5; 1}
```

Both those vectors are associated with the complex conjugate pair of eigenvalues `getRealEigenvalue(0) + getImagEigenvalue(0)*i` and `getRealEigenvalue(1) + getImagEigenvalue(1)*i`, but those vectors are not the actual eigenvectors.   The actual eigenvectors are the complex conjugate pairs
`eigenvector[0] + eigenvector[1]*i` and `eigenvector[0] - eigenvector[1]*i`.

Those vectors still don't "match" the results returned by numpy, but that is because the two libraries have not used the same normalization.  Eigenvectors are not unique; an eigenvector multiplied by any nonzero scalar (including a complex scalar) is still an eigenvector. The only difference between the Java result and the numpy result is a scalar multiplier.

For convenience, I'll convert the floating point values to their exact values.  That is, `-0.8660254038` is the floating point approximation of `-sqrt(3)/2`.  The Java math library is giving the following eigenvectors:

```
 [-sqrt(3)/2 + (1/2)*i]    and    [-sqrt(3)/2 - (1/2)*i]
 [      0    +     1*i]           [      0    -     1*i]
```

If you multiply the first eigenvector by -(sqrt(2)/2)*i and the second by (sqrt(2)/2)*i, you'll get the eigenvectors that were return by numpy.

Here's an ipython session with that calculation.  `v1` and `v2` are the vectors shown above.

```
In [20]: v1 = np.array([-np.sqrt(3)/2 + 0.5j, 1j])

In [21]: v1
Out[21]: array([-0.8660254+0.5j,  0.0000000+1.j ])

In [22]: v2 = np.array([-np.sqrt(3)/2 - 0.5j, -1j])

In [23]: v2
Out[23]: array([-0.8660254-0.5j,  0.0000000-1.j ])
```

Multiply `v1` by -(sqrt(2)/2)*i to get the first eigenvector returned by `numpy.linalg.eig`:

```
In [24]: v1*(-np.sqrt(2)/2*1j)
Out[24]: array([ 0.35355339+0.61237244j,  0.70710678-0.j        ])
```

Multiply `v2` by (sqrt(2)/2)*i to get the second eigenvector returned by `numpy.linalg.eig`:

```
In [25]: v2*(np.sqrt(2)/2*1j)
Out[25]: array([ 0.35355339-0.61237244j,  0.70710678+0.j        ])
```

For convenience, here's a repeat of the numpy calculation.  The columns of `evecs` are the eigenvectors.

```
In [28]: evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(a)

In [29]: evecs
Out[29]: 
array([[ 0.35355339+0.61237244j,  0.35355339-0.61237244j],
       [ 0.70710678+0.j        ,  0.70710678-0.j        ]])
```

Comment: First, thank you so much for your detailed answer :) Second, I hope you don't mind if I take this step by step, so I can understand everything. My current questions is - if eigenvector[0] and eigenvector[1] have two entries both (e.g. -0.8660254038; 0), where do you use the second entry (zero), and how did you come up with the "i" and "-i" (in the answer, after converting float points) ?
P.S. Also, I ran another example with {{2, -2}, {1, 1}} and by following your procedure, cannot get the right values :(

Comment: *"...where do you use the second entry (zero)"*  Because `eigenvector[0][1]` is 0, the second entry of the actual eigenvectors are both pure imaginary; the real part is 0.  I edited the ASCII representation of the eigenvectors to expliclty include "0 + ..."; that 0 is `eigenvector[0][1]`.

Comment: *"... following your procedure, cannot get the right values"*  You can't use the same constants (±sqrt(2)/2) as the scalar multiples.  For each eigenvector (more precisely, for each eigenvector associated with a [*simple* eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity)), there will be *some* constant that you can use to map the java result to the numpy result.

Comment: Is there a possibility to find that scalar ? Sorry for my lack of knowledge with linear algebra, the concept is new to me, and ive struck a lot of deadlines until now

Comment: Why do you need it?  As long as you are getting a correct eigenvector, the scaling doesn't really matter.

Comment: For testing purposes - so i can match results with Python. Unfortunately, I have zero support in team and cannot validate the results, but the Python app is tested and calculations are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128471/discussion-between-borgmater-and-warren-weckesser).

Comment: @borgmater In the end, how did u calculate the actual eigenvectors? Do u have an impelemantation? ty

Comment: I have managed to get the eigenvectors in both Python and Java, but I am still not sure how to obtain similar data for identical matrices

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to make it work. Here is why:

- the test suite [only tests real eigenvalues](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/d9e43edd13d55224fabc9a65b75884a77a3d56b7/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math4/linear/EigenDecompositionTest.java#L540)
- [mapMultiplyToSelf](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html) does not support complex arguments (so no multiplications by complex numbers including eigenvalues)

> As of 2.0, this class supports **only symmetric matrices, and hence computes only real realEigenvalues**. This implies the D matrix returned by getD() is always diagonal and the imaginary values returned getImagEigenvalue(int) and getImagEigenvalues() are always null. (c) [EigenDecomposition JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/EigenDecomposition.html)